# use variable from abstract in other class

Tags: java, android, listview, abstract-class

I am new to java and android development.I have created a abstract class for to display a listview in my app.I idea is that i will use common listview only changing its adapter.But i am not getting the listview defined in abstract class to use in the class which extends it.Please do help me out

Abstract Class Code

```
 public abstract class GeneralListView extends MasterFragment {

    protected ListView listView;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.common_list, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_common_list);
        return view;
    }

    public abstract void initializeList();

    public ListView getListView() {
        return listView;
    }


}
```

Class which extends the above class

```
 public class Test extends GeneralListView {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void initializeList() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(contextFragment, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getListView();
        initializeList();
    }

    @Override
    public ListView getListView() {
        return listView;
    }
}
```

Exception

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter); //null pointer exception
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to override getListVIew() in child class "Test" class and you dont need the  private ListView listView; attribute in your "Test" class,

To call a method or a variable in the super class you can call it directly if your not using any variable with the same name in your case you can call listView by using the super keyword

```
super.listView
```

and call the method getListView() with super keyword

```
super.getListView();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to either remove the

```
private ListView listView;
```

statement, or else in constructor do add the following,

```
public Test(){
listView = super.getListView;//I assume this would return initialized listview
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
private ListView listView;
```

and

```
@Override
public ListView getListView() {
    return listView;
}
```

from

```
public class Test extends GeneralListView {
```

You override the listView object in your Test subclass and that one is used instead of the instance from GeneralListView.

Answer (score 0):

could you check, whether you invoked a call for onCreateView method as I could only see this method initializing the listView reference.